# Displaying Two Values in single column

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have three columns that is Date, When (At, On etc) and Time in Kendo UI grid that displays value from a single Model. But I want only two columns to display that is Date and When (in this i want display both model.when and model.Time). How?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a template for combining both:

```
.Columns(columns =>
{
    ...
    columns.Bound(p => p.Date).ClientTemplate("/#= Date #/#= When #");
})
```

Of course, this only works for displaying (no edition).

Check [this link](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/documentation/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq) for more information on grid and templates.